# fatal error : database "root" does not exist - spree production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm using heroku and i want to create admin on production but it keeps returning `FATAL:  database "root" does not exist`. Perhaps I am not understanding correctly - my `database.yml` includes my development, test, and production credentials. The production details are from heroku. I dont understand why it wants `database root`. I am able to create admin and everything else on development. Not sure what is wrong.

Comment: are you using postgres?

Comment: yes, i am using that